# Python twice opens a file if uses subprocess.Popen for run another script

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have script test1.py (For example)

```
import test2


def main():
    f = open("File.txt")
    test2.run()

    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And test2.py

```
import subprocess, sys, os

def run():
    # Self run
    subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', '/C', 'start',
                          sys.executable, os.path.abspath(__file__)])

def main():
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that the startup of the second script re-open the file "File.txt". Why is the second script at startup opens the file?

```
D:\test>Handle.exe File.txt

Handle v4.0
Copyright (C) 1997-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

python.exe         pid: 9376   type: File           29C: D:\test\File.txt
python.exe         pid: 9792   type: File           29C: D:\test\File.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child process inherits a file handle for compatibility with the Unix model (see [PEP 446](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/#rationale) for more explanation). After the subprocess call, both the original and the new script should have access to the file; on Windows that means two separate file handles open.

A better idiom if you want to avoid this is to close the file before forking, either explicitly or using the `with` construct:

```
with open('File.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    pass # or do something with inputfile
```

Comment: I gave a simple example, for instructions my problems. My code is a bit more complicated, and therefore I can not close the file before forking. Whether it is possible to suppress a child process inherit file descriptor?

Comment: The subprocess can close it if you expect it to be a long-running process and if the multiple file handles are causing some additional problem.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Need setup close_fds=True in subprocess.Popen. Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

By the time you call `test2` your `test1` program has already opened the file. Therefore, when you create a subprocess that child process inherits any open files - including `File.txt`.

See the [notes on file inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) in the documentation for `subprocess`.

Comment: Can I forbid the child process inherits this open file?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Need setup close_fds=True in subprocess.Popen. Thank you very much for your answer